# How to properly parse JSONP callback function in Meteor?

Tags: api, meteor, jsonp

Does someone know how to parse JSONP callback in Meteor server methods?

I do

```
let response = HTTP.call('GET', AVIASALES_API_ENDPOINTS.getLocationFromIP, {
  params: {
    locale: 'en',
    callback: 'useriata',
    ip: clientIP
  }
});
```

in response.content I’ve got

```
useriata({"iata":"MSQ","name":"Minsk","country_name":"Belarus"})
```

How to properly parse it?

Comment: @Lzumskee javascript has JSON functionality built in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: @MarkUretsky, thanks, but i get a string, which contain json wrapped in function. I don't know how to properly parse it in Meteor.
JSON.parse returned `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`.
I need a suggestion how it situation resolved in Meteor apps

Comment: @lzumskee i answered with an example maybe this can help?

Comment: @MarkUretsky, thanks for answer. 
I created a playground for showing you what i do.
http://meteorpad.com/pad/ru3LTpELLGayJQppS/Leaderboard
Check please /server/app.js file and console. As you can see my response.data variable is null. In response.content i get a string with a callback, which i added before. I need parse it and return data from this callback.

Comment: @lzumskee thanks I will take a look now

Comment: @lzumskee se updated answer :)

Comment: @MarkUretsky, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could help to know what you really try to accomplish? But here is a working example meteor actually doesn't do anything unusual with the requests.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var result = HTTP.call("GET", "https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/meteor", {
        params: {},
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
        }
    });
    console.log(result.data); // it's js object you can do result.data.repositories[0].name
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)); // json string
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data))) // if for some reason you need to parse it this way will work, but seems unnecessary 
});
```

**Update:** The string you got back from the response wasn't valid JSON so you couldn't parse it used some regex to remove the invalid strings here is working example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/JCy5WkFsrtciG9PR5/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard